# NetBeans 7.2.1: Adding Dependency

Tags: android, maven, netbeans, dependencies

I'm running NetBeans 7.2.1.
I successfully built com.slidingmenu.lib.
I successfully built ABS.
NetBeans won't let me add ABS as a dependency to com.slidingmenu.example because NetBeans doesn't recognize ABS as an Android library.
Please help...I'll be your friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

1. Copied \ActionBarSherlock-master\library from my maven projects workspace to my ant projects workspace.
2. Renamed the copied directory from 'library' to 'com.actionbarsherlock'.
3. Opened a cmd prompt (I'm running Win7) in the new directory and ran 'android update project -p .' (don't forget the period at the end).
4. Opened the newly-create build.xml and renamed the project from 'library' to 'com.actionbarsherlock'.
5. Replaced the android-support-v4.jar in com.actionbarsherlock with the one in com.slidingmenu.lib (the whole point was to run/analyze the com.slidingmenu.example package).
6. Delete the pom.xml from the com.actionbarsherlock directory (so NetBeans 7.2.1 will recognize it as an Android Library).